# Synergy and Screensaver Sync

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I've been using [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) for some time now to sync an Ubuntu machine and a Windows XP box, and it works really great.  The one issue that still lingers is that I can't get the two machines to sync their screensaver locking.  Meaning, I would like that when the Linux box's screensaver is activate or deactivated, the Windows machine's screensaver follows suit.  I've tried uninstalling the Gnome screen saver and also tried a different session altogether (e.g. xfce), but nothing seems to work.  I've attached my configuration bellow.

What else can I try?

Thank you

```
section: screens
   linux-box:
   windows-box:
end

section: links
   linux-box:
       left = windows-box
   windows-box:
       right = linux-box
end

section: options
   screenSaverSync = true
end
```

Comment: You can't unlock a Windows screensaver programmatically; if that was your question. You can lock them, however.

Answer (score 2):

Based on past experience this is caused by the use of gnome-screensaver.  I have run into similar issues with screensaver syncing (from linux to linux), I was able to rectify this by installing and configuring xscreensaver on the systems in question. Additionally there seems to be an open enhancement request already posted to the synergy+ code group.

http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=112

My recommendation: Install xscreensaver on the linux system and see if that clears up the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. The screen savers sync and you don't want them to?

How about:

```
section: options
   screenSaverSync = false
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I would like them to sync and they do not (I've updated the question).